# Offline Reverse Geocoding in Python

Tags: python, geocoding, offline

I am writing a Python script that passes a latitude and longitude to a module and performs a reverse geocode function to return the address of the location.  I have been using Google's PyGeoCoder to do this, but it requires access to the Internet.  I am needing something similar to PyGeoCoder but open sourced and completely offline.

Answer (score 11):

I created a module to do exactly that: https://github.com/richardpenman/reverse_geocode

```
>>> import reverse_geocode 
>>> coordinates = (-37.81, 144.96), (31.76, 35.21)
>>> reverse_geocode.search(coordinates)
[{'city': 'Melbourne', 'code': 'AU', 'country': 'Australia'},
 {'city': 'Jerusalem', 'code': 'IL', 'country': 'Israel'}]
```

Internally it uses locations from the geonames database and a k-d tree to find the nearest neighbour.

Comment: How do you search for only one coordinate? I tried `coordinates = (-37.81, 144.96)` and then `reverse_geocode.search(coordinates)`, but I get an error saying: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.

Comment: Can you also add the US state, e.g. Texas, Florida, in the result?

Comment: The "search" method expects a list. Can use "get "method" for a single data point.

Comment: An improved version of this library is available at https://github.com/thampiman/reverse-geocoder

Comment: @Motin, this library is abandoned since at least 4 years. The original still gets updates.

Answer (score 7):

Have you considered using OpenStreetMap? You can download the whole [database (the "planet")](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) or one of the [extracts](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts) if you just need a specific area. Afterwards you can [filter](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter) out all [addresses](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3aaddr) and use the resulting data for your geocoding. There are several [search engines](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines) for OSM available, the most popular one is [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim). It is used on the main website and can do both geocoding and reverse-geocoding. So it might be a good starting point for your task.