# Is it possible to make local reverse-geocoding?

Tags: linux, reverse-geocoding

I am working on application, that receives lots coordinates & i need to locate each one. Google & other services have limitations. Perhaps there is solution, that could be used locally on linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least two older questions for this same problem, so maybe the answers provided in them gets you started in right directtion:
1. [Techniques for offline reverse geocoding on a mobile device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589519/techniques-for-offline-reverse-geocoding-on-a-mobile-device)
2. [Offline Reverse Geocoding in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803509/offline-reverse-geocoding-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Reverse geocoding is just a spatial search. You need data, for the US, you can use Tiger data from the Census or other spatial data for your coverage area. And you need a way to do a spatial query. This can be done using Postgresql and PostGIS or using Mapserver.org. If you want to license a solution, checkout http://imaptools.com/ (my consulting site). Getting good data probably presents one of the biggest challenges depending on your coverage needs.